# Iterating through dataframe, filtering it by first categorical value which appear and add subsequent categorical values to the total

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

guys

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

| Store | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Fish | 5 |
| B | Fish | 4 |
| C | Fish | 2 |
| D | Fish | 5 |

It has several items, distributed among the stores. Not all items are in all stores. What I need is iterate through the df and, for each item, I want the first store to receive the sum of Quantity for all the stores that item appears. I this case, my result would be:

| Store | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Fish | 16 |

Can you help me?

Comment: `df.groupby('Item', as_index=False).agg({'Store': 'first', 'Qty': 'sum'})`

Comment: Wow! This is so incredibly simple and efficient. Thanks, @mozway, you solved my problem!